# angular2-multiselect-dropdown onAddFilterNewItem not working

Tags: typescript, angular6, multi-select

Hi I am new to angular 6 and I using angular2-multiselect-dropdown but the thing is the onAddFilterNewItem not working.

link for the multiselect- https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/searchfilterAddNewItem

I tried to add settings and html tag which they have provided

HTML

```
<angular2-multiselect style="width: 100%" class="border-bot-none" 
name="businessImpact"
[data]="businessImpactList" [(ngModel)]="selectedbusinessImpactItems" 
[settings]="businessImpactdropdownSettings"
(onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)" 
(onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
(onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" 
(onAddFilterNewItem)="onAddItem($event)" required>
</angular2-multiselect>
```

.ts(multiselect dropdown setting)

```
this.businessImpactdropdownSettings = {
singleSelection: true,
text: 'Select Business Impact',
classes: 'custom-class-example',
primaryKey: 'impactStatement',
labelKey: 'impactStatement',
enableSearchFilter: true,
addNewItemOnFilter: true,
searchBy: ['impactStatement']
};

onAddItem(data: string) {
console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Stackblitz demo might be helpful